# How to select resultset given multiple searchTerms for each column in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, search

So I have a bunch of tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ManagerId] [int] NULL,
    [Active] [nchar](10) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LOB](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PersonLOB](
    [PersonId] [int] NULL,
    [LOBId] [int] NULL
)

INSERT [dbo].[LOB] ([Name]) VALUES (N'Banking')
INSERT [dbo].[LOB] ([Name]) VALUES (N'Insurance')
INSERT [dbo].[LOB] ([Name]) VALUES (N'Real Estate')
INSERT [dbo].[LOB] ([Name]) VALUES (N'Retail Brokerage')
INSERT [dbo].[LOB] ([Name]) VALUES (N'Merger & Acquisition')


INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([FirstName], [LastName], [ManagerId], [Active]) VALUES ( N'Alfredo', N'Mando', NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([FirstName], [LastName], [ManagerId], [Active]) VALUES ( N'Alejandro', N'Mendoza', NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([FirstName], [LastName], [ManagerId], [Active]) VALUES ( N'Berto', N'Lao', 2, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([FirstName], [LastName], [ManagerId], [Active]) VALUES ( N'Benjamin', N'Mindu', 2, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([FirstName], [LastName], [ManagerId], [Active]) VALUES ( N'Ben', N'Uy', NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([FirstName], [LastName], [ManagerId], [Active]) VALUES ( N'Bernie', N'Sanders', NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([FirstName], [LastName], [ManagerId], [Active]) VALUES ( N'Benjamin', N'Santos', 3, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([FirstName], [LastName], [ManagerId], [Active]) VALUES ( N'Cathy', N'Zaragosa', 2, 1)

INSERT [dbo].[PersonLOB] ([PersonId], [LOBId]) VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[PersonLOB] ([PersonId], [LOBId]) VALUES (2, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[PersonLOB] ([PersonId], [LOBId]) VALUES (2, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[PersonLOB] ([PersonId], [LOBId]) VALUES (2, 3)
INSERT [dbo].[PersonLOB] ([PersonId], [LOBId]) VALUES (3, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[PersonLOB] ([PersonId], [LOBId]) VALUES (4, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[PersonLOB] ([PersonId], [LOBId]) VALUES (4, 5)
INSERT [dbo].[PersonLOB] ([PersonId], [LOBId]) VALUES (5, 3)
INSERT [dbo].[PersonLOB] ([PersonId], [LOBId]) VALUES (5, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[PersonLOB] ([PersonId], [LOBId]) VALUES (6, 5)
INSERT [dbo].[PersonLOB] ([PersonId], [LOBId]) VALUES (7, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[PersonLOB] ([PersonId], [LOBId]) VALUES (8, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[PersonLOB] ([PersonId], [LOBId]) VALUES (8, 3)
```

So on the UI side, display a sample data

```
FirstName    LastName    LOBs               ManagerName        Active

Alfredo      Mando       Banking                               Y
Alejandro    Mendoza     Banking, Insurance                    Y
Berto        Lao         Insurance          Alejando Mendoza   Y
.
.
.
```

So the question is

How do I select resultset given multiple search terms filters for each column in TSQL?

Given Sample search term filter from the UI

FirstName: 'al', 'o'

LastName: 'do'

LOB: 'Banking'

Active: 'Y'

Expected Result:

```
FirstName    LastName    LOBs               ManagerName        Active

Alfredo      Mando       Banking                               Y
Alejandro    Mendoza     Banking, Insurance                    Y
```

Comment: None of those people have a name like "Al, o", what you're asking here is unclear

Comment: Alfredo and Alejando has 'Al' and 'o'

Comment: What does your current SQL look like?

Comment: Echoing Matt Evans: a good SO question should pre-emptively answer the question of 'What have you tried?'

Comment: I don't get what *the* question is.  Is it how to produce the data in the structure that you have shown?  Or is the question on how to filter an existing query for the condition you specify?